# Audacity isn't playing any sound and it makes 30 tracks instead of one

Tags: sound, audacity

When I play anything in audacity there is no sound. I uninstalled it but it didn't work. Before I installed it through the Ubuntu software center, so I reinstalled it this time using a command. Still no change. Also every time I record it makes 30 tracks instead of one.

Comment: Youtube was playing sound while Audacity wasn't... But now it's not playing any sound either. Also I muted the master volume But sound was still playing through a music player. I'm having so many sound problems.

Comment: I just updated Ubuntu. No changes Except Audacity no longer makes 30 tracks every time I press record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay for anyone else who has the same problem, No sound playing from almost anything, I figured out how to fix it. Instead of "Speakrs" being selected in the sound settings menu in the output tab I selected one of the USB devices. This fixed both audacity and Youtube not playing any sound. And the extra 29 tracks that Audacity was making was just A bug that was recently fixed (I guess).

Answer (score 1):

Audacity has sound settings.

On the top left go to <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> <kbd>Devices</kbd> and in Devices choose which device you want your sound to play through.

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and test to see if that solves your problem.  I'm using version 2.1.0 which you will find under Help and About Audacity at the top and that works.

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too. I have audacity as default preinstalled on my Ubuntu Studio 18.04.

Then i tried to uninstall it, the re install it back.

sudo apt-get install audacity

then, everything's back normal.